# Organize MySQL data by month using php/codeigntier

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to organize the user login date by the month. Currently, I am doing it like this in code igniter:

My Model code:

```
public function getApril(){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where('Date >=','2018-04-01');
  $this->db->where('Date <=','2018-04-30');
  $this->db->from('user_data');
  $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
  return $count;
}

public function getMarch(){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where('Date >=','2018-03-01');
  $this->db->where('Date <=','2018-03-31');
  $this->db->from('user_data');
  $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
  return $count;
}

public function getFebruary(){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where('Date >=','2018-02-01');
  $this->db->where('Date <=','2018-02-28');
  $this->db->from('user_data');
  $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
  return $count;
}
```

My controller code:

```
public function index(){
  $data["april"]= $this->login_model->getApril();
  $data["march"]= $this->login_model->getMarch();
  $data["february"]= $this->login_model->getFebruary();
  $this->load->view('main/header');
  $this->load->view('main/body', $data);
  $this->load->view('main/footer');
}
```

And in my view I just use echo to display the result, like so:

```
<p><strong><?php echo $april?></strong></p>
```

This seems like a very redundant method. I'm sure there is a better way of going about this.

I tried using `'group_by'` like so: `$this->db->group_by('MONTH(Date)');` but that only returns the number of months in the database and not the number of logins in each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want all months and years your suggestion with `$this->db->group_by('MONTH(Date)')` was pretty close

Something like

Model

```
public function getDataByMonth()
{
    $query = $this->db
        ->select('count(*) AS count, MONTH(Date) AS month, YEAR(Date) AS year')
        ->from('user_data')
        ->group_by('MONTH(Date)')
        ->group_by('YEAR(Date)')
        ->order_by('YEAR(Date)', 'DESC')
        ->order_by('MONTH(Date)', 'DESC')
        ->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->view('main/header');
    $this->load->view('main/body', ['data' => $this->login_model->getDataByMonth()]);
    $this->load->view('main/footer');
}
```

view

```
<?php
foreach ($data AS $obj)
{
    $objDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('n', $obj->month);
?>
    <p><strong><?php echo $objDateTime->format('F').' '.$obj->year.' | '.$obj->count; ?></strong></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Just a note, for your view code I think you forgot to close the php tag. Replacing the last 2 lines with <?php } ?> should do the trick.

Comment: Just a followup question if I wanted to formate the date for week number, how would I do that?

Comment: by week number you have to group it by week i guess .., do you need support here ? because if so - pls open a new question .

Answer (score 2):

**You can use [`MONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) method**

And just use one function to access the data

```
public function getMonth($theMonthNumber){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where('MONTH(Date)', $theMonthNumber);
  $this->db->from('user_data');
  $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
  return $count;
}
```

And, **how to count each month log in?**

**Try with this query**

```
SELECT MONTH(Date) as the_month, COUNT(*) as the_value
FROM user_data
WHERE user_data.user_id = "the_user_id_i_send"
GROUP BY MONTH(Date)
```

If you use this with codeigniter the function will look like this

```
function some_function_name($user_id){
     $query = $this->db->query('the same query i wrote before')
           ->result_array();
     return $query;
 }
```

the expected output should be an array with associative keys related to the month, **Example output**

```
  echo json_encode($query[0]); //the first month where the user has registers
  echo json_encode($query[3]); //the third month....and so on..
```

And of course you can filter this array.

(When i get home i will try to complement more the answer.)

Hope my answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

your model file

```
public function getDataByMonth($start, $end){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where('Date >=', $start);
  $this->db->where('Date <=', $end);
  $this->db->from('user_data');
  $count = $this->db->count_all_results();
  return $count;
}
```

then create a months array that contains the name of the month, start and end dates like this then pass it to your controller function

```
$months = array(
    "january"   =>  array("01-01-2018", "31-01-2018"),
    "february"  =>  array("01-02-2018", "28-02-2018"),
    "march"     =>  array("01-03-2018", "31-01-2018")
);
```

last in your controller

```
public function index($months){
    foreach ($months as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = $this->login_model->getDataByMonth($value[0], $value[1]);
    }
  $this->load->view('main/header');
  $this->load->view('main/body', $data);
  $this->load->view('main/footer');
}
```

Comment: This is an incremental improvement, but still fairly tedious.

Comment: I agree with cale_b. For example in 2019 I would need to create a new array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db
        ->select('count(*) AS count, MONTH(Date) AS month, YEAR(Date) AS year')
         ->group_by('MONTH(Date)')
        ->group_by('YEAR(Date)')
        ->order_by('YEAR(Date)', 'DESC')
        ->order_by('MONTH(Date)', 'DESC')
        ->get("tablename");
```